# bitbucket pipeline & docker for ios build Ionic project

Tags: docker, ionic-framework, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I integrated Bit bucket pipeline and docker for my ionic 3 project currently its done for android. When i try to integrate the same for ios build there is no docker image available for ios i just want to know is it possible to build ios app using the bitbucket pipeline and docker ?

Answer (score -4):

You can use any build environment you need, just pull the right docker image:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-docker-images-as-build-environments-792298897.html

In your case, you may have to build your own image and push it to a repository like Docker Hub.